# Stopping python-telegram-bot gracefully after finishing job_queue

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-telegram-bot

I have deployed a python script on AWS Lambda, running python-telegram-bot (version == 20.3)
I have set the scheduler to invoke the function regularly.
I don't need the bot to receive any updates, I just want the bot to finish the job_queue and then exit gracefully.
The main part of the code is as below:

def main(event, context):

```
print("Initializing the telegram bot...")

application = ApplicationBuilder().token(BOT_TOKEN).build()

# echo_handler = MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & (~filters.COMMAND), echo)
start_handler = CommandHandler('chatid', check_chat_id)


application.add_handler(start_handler)
# application.add_handler(echo_handler)


print("Creating job queue...")

job_queue = application.job_queue
job_check_promotion = job_queue.run_once(check_promotion, 10)

print("Starting the bot...")

application.run_polling()
```

For now, I end the function check_promotion by raising KeyboardInterrupt.
I know I should not use run_polling and KeyboardInterrupt by ending the script with error.
But I don't know how to modify.

I have tried looking up the documentation. But I can hardly comprehend.
I expect someone can help me modify the code so that it can end gracefully on Lambda.

Comment: AFAIK AWS Lambda works by invoking a new process for each incoming update. And you define a handler. Yet you say that you don't need to receive updates. It's not clear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: @CallMeStag I have set AWS Lambda to run every 15 minutes to get any update from a website and then use telegram bot to send the message to the group. So there is no need for the bot to receive updates from the chat. It just push messages.